# Best Way to Sense Rubiks Cube Movements

Tags: accelerometer, motion

I was wondering what was, in your opinion, the best way to study the different motions of a Rubiks Cube.
I want to be able to recognize what face moved and in what direction.

Would I be able to get the direction and the face with accelerometers/gyro and if yes how many would I need?
If you have ever used a Leapmotion or Kinect, is it possible to achieve this using those?

Comment: "in your opinion" -- Opinion questions really aren't a good fit for this site.  Can you ask this question in a different way so that the answers could be based on facts instead?